# spark.table vs sql() AccessControlException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to run

```
  spark.table("db.table")
    .groupBy($"date")
    .agg(sum($"total"))
```

returns

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to alter table. java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=user, access=WRITE, inode="/sources/db/table":tech_user:bgd_group:drwxr-x---
```

the same script but written as

```
  sql("SELECT sum(total) FROM db.table group by date").show()
```

returns actual result.

I don't understand why this is happening. What is the first script trying to write exactly? Some staging result?
I have read permission for this table and I'm only trying to perform some aggregations.
Using Spark 2.2 for this.

Comment: try set all permission to  "/sources/db/table" for user=user

Comment: Can you check `spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode` setting? "Unable to alter table" could be result of Spark trying to save inferred schema.

Comment: @mazaneicha Where can I find it? Don't see it in hive/hdfs/core-site or spark-defaults.conf.

Comment: Try,`spark.conf.getAll.foreach(println)` to see if it was explicitly set. If not in the list, likely it is the default which is `INFER_AND_SAVE` in Spark 2.2 according to this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-21-to-22

Comment: @mazan You were right. I had to set it manualy `new SparkConf().set("spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode", "NEVER_INFER")`. You can post the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @eugene-cuz Good, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark 2.2, the default for `spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode` was changed from `NEVER_INFER` to `INFER_AND_SAVE`. This mode causes Spark to infer (from underlying files) and **try to save** case-sensitive schema into Hive metastore. This will fail if the user executing the command wasn't granted permissions to update HMS.

Obvious workaround is to set inference mode back to `NEVER_INFER`, or `INFER_ONLY` if application relies on column names as they present in files (CaseSensitivE).