# MetaException(message:Partition spec is incorrect): proper way to fix case-sensitive insert from Spark into partitioned Hive table

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I have partitioned Hive table described as

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRADES
(
    TRADE_ID                          STRING,
    TRADE_DATE                        INT,
-- ...
)
    PARTITIONED BY (BUSINESS_DATE INT)
    STORED AS PARQUET;
```

When I insert the data from Spark-based Java application as

```java
try (SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
        .config(new SparkConf())
        .enableHiveSupport()
//        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
//        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
//        .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
        .getOrCreate()) {

  dataset.select(columns(joinedDs, businessDate))
        .write()
        .format("parquet")
        .option("compression", "snappy")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .insertInto("TRADES"));
}

//...

private Column[] columns(Dataset<Row> dataset, LocalDate businessDate) {
  List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String column : appConfig.getColumns()) {
    columns.add(dataset.col(column));
  }
  columns.add(lit(dateToInteger(businessDate)).as("BUSINESS_DATE"));
  return columns.toArray(new Column[0]);
}
```

it fails with the following exception:

```
23/01/27 10:39:26 ERROR metadata.Hive: Exception when loading partition with parameters  partPath=hdfs://path-to-trades/.hive-staging_hive_2023-01-27_10-38-29_374_384898966661095068-1/-ext-10000/BUSINESS_DATE=20221230,  table=trades,  partSpec={business_date=, BUSINESS_DATE=20221230},  replace=false,  listBucketingEnabled=false,  isAcid=false,  hasFollowingStatsTask=false
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Partition spec is incorrect. {business_date=, BUSINESS_DATE=20221230})
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartitionInternal(Hive.java:1662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.lambda$loadDynamicPartitions$4(Hive.java:1970)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Partition spec is incorrect. {business_date=, BUSINESS_DATE=20221230})
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.makePartName(Warehouse.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.makePartPath(Warehouse.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.genPartPathFromTable(Hive.java:1751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartitionInternal(Hive.java:1607)
    ... 5 more
```

I fix this issue by specifying **lower case** for partitioning column both in DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRADES
(
    TRADE_ID                          STRING,
    TRADE_DATE                        INT,
-- ...
)
    PARTITIONED BY (business_date INT) -- <-- lower case!
    STORED AS PARQUET;
```

and Java code

```java
columns.add(lit(dateToInteger(businessDate)).as("business_date")); // <-- lower case!
```

I suspect there is a way to configure Spark to use Hive's case (or vice versa) or make them case-insensitive. Tried to uncomment properties for SparkSession, but no luck.

Does anyone know how to implement in properly? I use Spark 2.4.0 and Hive 2.1.1.

[image]

P.S. Output of `sparkSession.sql("describe formatted TRADES").show(false)`:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|            col_name|           data_type|comment|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|           ROW_INDEX|                 int|   null|
|  OP_GENESIS_FEED_ID|              string|   null|
|       business_date|                 int|   null|
|# Partition Infor...|                    |       |
|          # col_name|           data_type|comment|
|       business_date|                 int|   null|
|                    |                    |       |
|# Detailed Table ...|                    |       |
|            Database|             managed|       |
|               Table|              trades|       |
|               Owner|             managed|       |
|        Created Time|Mon Jan 30 19:59:...|       |
|         Last Access|Thu Jan 01 02:00:...|       |
|          Created By|Spark 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1|       |
|                Type|             MANAGED|       |
|            Provider|                hive|       |
|    Table Properties|[transient_lastDd...|       |
|            Location|....................|       |
|       Serde Library|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|         InputFormat|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|        OutputFormat|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|  Storage Properties|[serialization.fo...|       |
|  Partition Provider|             Catalog|       |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: When reading from and writing to Hive metastore Parquet tables, Spark SQL will try to use its own Parquet support instead of Hive SerDe for better performance. This behavior is controlled by the `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` configuration, and is turned on by default.

You could try to have this property set to false and give it a try to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: @DataWrangler thanks for your comment, but the issue is still here

Comment: Thanks for checking it, can you also try this property setting, `spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode` https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30559  based on the issue what I understand is it should work from the second time the table is referenced. I haven't tried this myself just a suggestion.

Comment: Weird enough, looking into https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541069/12473843 I've tried `.config("spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode", "NEVER_INFER")`, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: [Hive DDL doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL): "Table names and column names are case insensitive...". Hive converts all column names to lower case, and partition columns become (part of) sub-dir names.

Comment: @mazaneicha If we are talking about columns created within `create table ()` clause then I agree, though apparently this is not true for partition column.

Comment: Can you try `sparkSession.sql("describe formatted trades").show(false)` and paste the output into your question?

Comment: I think regardless of whether you define `BUSINESS_DATE` as lowercase or uppercase, the partitions in hadoop will be using lowercase `business_date`, as in
`[hdfs@gateway ~]# hadoop fs -ls /tmp/hive/trades_allcaps
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - spark supergroup          0 2023-01-31 12:24 /tmp/hive/trades_allcaps/**business_date=20230131**
`

Comment: Interesting. I was sure this is about Parquet file format: 

"Although Spark SQL itself is not case-sensitive, Hive compatible file formats such as Parquet are. Spark SQL must use a case-preserving schema when querying any table backed by files containing case-sensitive field names or queries may not return accurate results."

https://medium.com/@an_chee/why-using-mixed-case-field-names-in-hive-spark-sql-is-a-bad-idea-95da8b6ec1e0

Comment: You can use [`parquet-tools`](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/parquet-1.10.x/parquet-tools) to inspect schema/metadata of generated parquet files. There, "regular" column names would be same as you defined them in create table, I expect. Partition columns are special, they become dir names so they won't be there at all.